# dataTables jQuery não funciona corretamente com acentuações

Tags: jquery, codificação-de-caracteres, jquery-ui, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o plugin `dataTables` do `jQuery` e o problema está acontecendo por causa de palavras com acentuações. Por exemplo, tem na lista vários itens, e um deles se chama **café**. Caso na barra de busca eu procure por **café**, irá me retornar certinho só itens com a palavra café. Agora se eu coloco **cafe**, sem o acento, então ele não me retorna itens que tem **café**. O que pode ser feito nesse caso?

Comment: Sua questão não está bem formulada, pois a consulta está funcionando corretamente é você que deseja um comportamento atípico(diferente).

Comment: Podes completar a pergunta com código e um exemplo?